# How to keep "DropdownMenu" open when clicking on a "DropdownItem"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need that when I click on a DropdownItem from my ButtonDropdown from '***reactstrap***' do not close ***DropdownMenu***. And when I clicking outside of ***DropdownMenu*** it closes.

I have already tried to control by state that I pass in the parameter **"isOpen"** and with the function that I happen in the **"toggle"** of ***ButtonDropdown***, but it does not work.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Collapse, Button, CardBody, Card, ButtonDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

class DropdownTest extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       dropdownOpen: false, 
     }
     this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);
   }

   toggleDropdown() {       
     this.setState({
       dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen,
     });
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <ButtonDropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggleDropdown} >
           <DropdownToggle caret color="info" className={'btn-rounded'}>Title Test
           </DropdownToggle>
           <DropdownMenu>            
             <DropdownItem >Follow</DropdownItem>
           </DropdownMenu>
         </ButtonDropdown>
       </div>   
     )
   }      
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z08Q.jpg "expected result"

Comment: Did mean for it to be `toggle {this.toggleDropdown}` without the `=`?

Comment: sorry stever, It was my typo here on the stack, but I already fixed it and the problem is not this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a condition.  Perhaps something like this, in render

```
if(dropdownOpen) {     
  var showDrop = ( 
  <DropdownMenu>            
   <DropdownItem >Follow</DropdownItem>
  </DropdownMenu>)
} else{ showDrop = null }

<ButtonDropdown onClick={() => this.toggleDropdown()}>
  <DropdownToggle caret color="info" className={'btn-rounded'}>
    Title Test
  </DropdownToggle>
    {showDrop}
</ButtonDropdown>
```